# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 at bt.ddd.main(ddd.java:13)

Tags: java

Because I recently learned java so I need a simple way to solve the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String test = "F: M1,“Khan lanh”,1; M2,”Trai cay dia”,3; M3,”Chuoi luoc”,1; M4,”Canh chua”,3";
    String [] result= test.split("F:");
    for (int i=1;i<result.length;i++){
        String [] result1=result[i].split(";");             
        for (int j=0;j<result1[i].length();j++){
            String [] result2= result1[j].split(",");
            for(String s: result2){
                System.out.println(s);
            }   
        }   
    }       
}
```

Which is far from what I would expect:

```
M1
“Khan lanh”
1
M2
”Trai cay dia”
3
M3
”Chuoi luoc”
1
M4
”Canh chua”
3
```

Comment: `result1[i].length()` looks suspicious

Comment: use the dubugger to see how many item are in the arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the condition in your second `for` loop to something like this:-

```
for (int j = 0; j < result1.length; j++) { // traverse over all elements of result1 and thus use its length
```

What you did was `result1[i].length()` - which will consider the length of the splitted string present in the `i`th index of the `result1` array, which is wrong.

Also, on a side note, shouldnt't your first `for` start with `0` and instead of `1`(just saw your String. `1` should do in your case.)